# How to select elements from a list of pairs based on first element belonging to a different list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, conditional, subset

This is my very first question and I really appreciate this ability and thankful the community.

I have two lists and need to select only those pairs from the first list, first element of which is present in the second list:

I have:

```
listA = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "e"}};
listB = {1, 3, 5};
```

I need to get

```
{{1, "a"}, {3, "c"}, {5, "e"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short cut:

```
Extract[listA, List /@ listB]
```

{{1, "a"}, {3, "c"}, {5, "e"}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Position[listA[[All,1]], Alternatives@@listB]//Extract[listA,#]&

(* {{1, a}, {3, c}, {5, e}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
listA = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "e"}};
listB = {1, 3, 5};
DeleteCases[listA, _?(! MemberQ[listB, First@#] &)]
```

OR

```
Cases[listA, {a_, _} /; MemberQ[listB, a]]
```

OR

```
Select[listA, IntersectingQ[{First@#}, listB] &]
```

---

Result:

> {{1, "a"}, {3, "c"}, {5, "e"}}

Comment: Thank you, Syed. This works, but I was playing with Select and am happy Nasser has a solution I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the other two methods you listed. Perfect! Thank you

Comment: @IgorBinder, please wait for a day and then select an answer. What is perfect for one scenario may not be so for another.

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways

```
listA = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "e"}};
listB = {1, 3, 5};
Select[listA,MemberQ[listB,First[#]]&]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is precisely what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases`, `FreeQ` and `Condition`:

```
Cases[listA, {x_, y_} /; ! FreeQ[listB, x]]
(*{{1, "a"}, {3, "c"}, {5, "e"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
☺ = #[[#2]] &;

listA ~☺~ listB
```

> ```
> {{1, "a"}, {3, "c"}, {5, "e"}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use `<|  |>`

```
{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}, {5, "e"}} //
Rule@@@#& //
Apply[Association] //
KeyTake[{1,3,5}] //
KeyValueMap[List]
```

> {{1, a}, {3, c}, {5, e}}

Comment: (With the caveat that you need the keys (first entry in the list) to be unique; if they are not, then entries may be lost.)

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier in that case, for example, `<| 1 -> {"a", "b"} |>` could work for dup keys.